# Crontab script not updating postgresql database; running the command in the terminal updates the database

Tags: postgresql, cron

I have a remote database that I'd like to copy to my local database twice a day. When on the command line and run

```
ssh abc@ip_address 'pg_dump --clean -Z 9 -U user remote_db' | zcat | psql local_db
```

I successfully get a local copy of the db.

In my crontab file I have -

```
0 10 * * * ssh abc@ip_address 'pg_dump --clean -Z 9 -U user remote_db' | zcat | psql local_db

0 14 * * * ssh abc@ip_address 'pg_dump --clean -Z 9 -U user remote_db' | zcat | psql local_db

MAILTO="user@example.com"
```

I get a notification on the command line that I've received new mail, but the database is not updated. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: "my crontab" — are you referring to `/etc/crontab`. or something in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`? Is it possible the two cases are executing under a different user?

Comment: Thanks Amadan, there is no /etc/crontab or /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ file. I don't think they are executing under a different user, there is only one user on this local host.

Comment: If you are on any kind of Unix, you almost certainly have your own user account, and `root` (and a bunch of other system accounts). You might check with `whoami` who the user is (by executing it from inside "your crontab"). If executing with a different user, `ssh` would not find your identity file (`id_rsa` or whatever you have set up for that `ip_address`).

Comment: Yes, thank you, you are correct, my local host user is different from my remote user, if this is the problem, do you have a suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Not local vs remote. The user executing your crontab command vs the user executing your command from command-line. You still haven't answered which file is "my crontab", nor which OS you are using, so it is kind of hard to tell you details. You could make cron execute under a different user, or you could use `-i` switch to tell `ssh` where to find the identity file...

Comment: Thanks, I'm on Mac / OS X; per your advice I was able to use sudo -i to access the crontab file in /var/at/tabs.

Comment: The mail should have some details about what went wrong.  I'm guessing there's an issue with the ssh key or psql is not in the path.  Try adding the full path to psql in your crontab as that's the easiest change to make.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, checked the mail, found the error "/bin/sh: psql: command not found", used "which psql" to find the full path at /usr/local/bin/psql, replaced the "psql" command in the crontab file with this full path, and it is working now.